# INSERT or SUM multiple rows at once

Tags: performance, upsert, cockroachdb

I want to increase multiple values at once, with the following logic: if the value does not exist, create a new row with the value, otherwise sum with the existing value on the database.

To achieve this I currently doing the following PostgreSQL request:

```sql
 INSERT INTO
        data (id, value1, value2, value3)
 VALUES
        ('cd46849e-c0c5-41c3-b221-95aef0a6bca7',0,0,20),
        ('9781bdc9-0e7f-4c2a-83ec-71a6e6fa14f9',-3,0,20),
        ('cb0ef8b8-9dc8-4216-b718-e18bb16a577b',10,10,0),
ON CONFLICT
        (id)
DO UPDATE SET 
       (value1, value2, value3) = (
         (data.value1 + excluded.value1), 
         (data.value2 + excluded.value2), 
         (data.value3 + excluded.value3)
       )
```

This is used in CockroachDB, but with many updates on the same row it seems to hit some performance issues.

What is the best way to achieve this request?

What is the best database that permits this behaviour (it does not need to be a relational database)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to make this fast on writes is to avoid having multiple processes needing to update the same row at the same time, and move the work of adding to reads or an asynchronous job. In CockroachDB, you'd do something like this: make `id` not be the primary key (if you don't set a primary key, it'll use a hidden random rowid as the primary key automatically) but create a non-unique secondary index on it. Then change your SQL to

```sql
INSERT INTO
        data (id, value1, value2, value3)
 VALUES
        ('cd46849e-c0c5-41c3-b221-95aef0a6bca7',0,0,20),
        ('9781bdc9-0e7f-4c2a-83ec-71a6e6fa14f9',-3,0,20),
        ('cb0ef8b8-9dc8-4216-b718-e18bb16a577b',10,10,0),
```

and

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(value1), SUM(value2), SUM(value3) FROM data GROUP BY id
```

You can also use a [changefeed](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/change-data-capture-overview.html) or [materialized view](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/views.html) to do the addition work asynchronously and store it in another table. The changefeed strategy would let you "garbage collect" inserts afterwards.

This pattern is also supported in non-relational databases--without ACID constraints, it's the only reliable way to avoid consistency bugs.